# LiveQuery not working in combination with whereEqualTo

Tags: flutter, parse-platform, parse-live-query

I am trying to establish a LiveQuery with a query using the `whereEqualTo` statement. Once I start my app the debug console gives me the following - so I assume the connection is fine.

```
flutter: LiveQuery: : Socket opened
flutter: LiveQuery: : ConnectMessage: {op: connect, applicationId: SL0zySmAoBus5vtNoTPis7odg85IUCdEwFpXM1cX, clientKey: OGNqC9YZMsOK7KaRt0JDkvDm13AnhJUka2WxipaW}
flutter: LiveQuery: : Listen: {"op":"connected","clientId":"073e7e6d-ba78-47bb-860b-41cbda2f32f4"}
flutter: Re subscription:{}
flutter: LiveQueryReconnectingController: LiveQueryClientEvent.connected
flutter: LiveQuery: : SubscribeMessage: {op: subscribe, requestId: 1, query: {className: rounds, where: {commonId: h1qUwTisSQ}, fields: [contribution]}}
flutter: LiveQuery: : Listen: {"op":"subscribed","clientId":"073e7e6d-ba78-47bb-860b-41cbda2f32f4","requestId":1}
```

However, if I update the database there is nothing received. Also if I comment out `..whereEqualTo('commonId', 'h1qUwTisSQ')` the live query is working as it should. The exact same query works as Future object.

The query looks as follows and I expected to receive updated data everytime I update the database.

```
class _CommonState extends State<Common> {
  final LiveQuery liveQuery = LiveQuery();

  final QueryBuilder<ParseObject> queryContribution =
      QueryBuilder<ParseObject>(ParseObject('rounds'))
        ..whereEqualTo('commonId', 'h1qUwTisSQ')
        ..orderByAscending('createdAt')
        ..keysToReturn(['contribution']);
  startLiveQuery();

  void startLiveQuery() async {
    Subscription subscription =
        await liveQuery.client.subscribe(queryContribution);

    subscription.on(LiveQueryEvent.update, (value) {
      debugPrint("OBJECT UPDATE: $value");
    });
  }
```

Note: `commonId` is a Pointer column in the table `rounds`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. A pointer in Parse Server cannot be specified by a simple String. Instead it can be specified by the following notation.

```
final QueryBuilder<ParseObject> queryContribution =
      QueryBuilder<ParseObject>(ParseObject('rounds'))
        ..whereEqualTo('commonId', {
          '__type': 'Pointer',
          'className': 'commons',
          'objectId': 'KAXFZN9Wj8'
        })
        ..orderByAscending('createdAt')
        ..keysToReturn(['contribution']);
```